# Calculate time elapsed Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to calculate the number of months a certain object has aged in 2016.

Background:

This is a depreciation recalculation for accounting purposes within excel. I have a large list of assets that have a ‘start date’ and ‘end date’. I would like to calculate the number of months have elapsed for that asset in 2016.

The problem:

Assets are constantly being added to the list, so you have many different start and end dates. Some assets start in 2016, some assets end in 2016. I cannot determine a formula that will simply calculate the # of months that asset has in 2016.

Example issue:

I have an asset with a start date of April 1st, 2016. 
I have an asset with a an end date of April 30, 2016.

Is there a formula for how much time has that asset spent in the year 2016?

Answer (score 1):

How about the `DATEDIF` function - with your start/end date in cell **A1**:

```
=DATEDIF("1/1/2016",A1,"m")
```

This is an old function which you cannot find in Excel's list of functions, but you can read more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c)

---

Note that this will give you an error for dates in **A1** that are before 1/1/2016 so you might want to wrap `IFERROR` around the formula like so:

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF("1/1/2016",A1,"m"),0)
```

Comment: Hi CallumDA33, thanks for the response. I am familiar with the DATEDIF function, but the problem is that the formula would show an asset with a start date of April 1 having only 3 months in 2016, when the answer should be 9 (assuming todays date is 31.12.16).


I think the problem arises from the use of four dates(1.start date of asset 2. end date of asset 3. start date of period used 4. end date of period used)

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to include some examples along with what output you expect to see. The obvious solution to your example above is just doing `12-DATEDIF` to the beginning of the formula to give you the `9` months in 2016